# Structure structure alignment using combinatorial extensions

Tags: python-2.7, alignment, biopython

I am trying to find a tool that performs structure structure alignment for two sequences given their residues using combinatorial extensions (CE). I found a tool based on combinatorial extensions provided by the protein data bank: http://source.rcsb.org/jfatcatserver/ 
However I was wondering if there is any python module or a class for structure to structure alignment that I can implement. I have found the structure Alignment tool from Bio.PDB, but is poorly documented. is there any python module or library that implements this method? Thanks.

Comment: Your best option is to use jfatcat through a subprocess. Biopython do this all over the place (wrappers for blast, clustal, muscle, Tcoffee, etc) http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec91

Comment: is there any documentation provided concerning the wrappers for Jfatcat and Jce (combinatorial extensions) I'm assuming it's within the PDB tools in Biopython... as in Bio.PDB.---- but I cant seem to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doesn't fit as a comment]

I doubt that wrap exists. You'll have to scratch your own itch here: experiment with the command in a console, and then put it in a `subprocess.Popen()`. The wrappers won't save you from work, e.g.

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline

muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(input="opuntia.fasta")
stdout, stderr = muscle_cline()

align = AlignIO.read(stdout, "fasta")
```

Is about the same as:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["muscle", "-in", "opuntia.fasta"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

align = AlignIO.read(proc.stdout, "fasta")
```

Maybe if you put this code inside a bigger app (like the external commands in Bioedit), you can assert that the user input fits the values that the wrapped command expects, or if a required flag is present... that's where the wrappers shine.

Comment: I see, I'll try and fit these apps in a sub-process then. I'll see what I can do. Thank you!